# QueryException Laravel : Driver not found

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I am facing a strange error with laravel under ubuntu using PostgreSql.
Its NOT a PDOException. The database migration is successful so all driver are set and PDO connection is also established. But why this error?

Didn't find much about it in google. I am attaching the screenshot.

This is NOT homestead rather own lamp stack.
[image]

Edit: 
There is no problem even with tinker
[image]

Regards

Comment: It is indeed a PDOException, you can see it in the stack on the left. If the database is connecting normally in other places, I would see what is different about this specific request that it might not be. Are you loading the environment differently? Are you modifying config options? Things of that nature.

Comment: https://github.com/ArpanKIIT2017/blog4b

Comment: that's my github repo for this project. Kindly help me resolve this issue

Comment: did you try to use `pgsql` connection?

Comment: Its a Laravel project so I did not make any connection manually rather gave credentials to the .env file.

Comment: normally i am able to access database while migration and normally through command line

Comment: @ArpanMukherjee Are you using Apache? Did you enable php-mysql extension in apache setting ?

Comment: I am using postgre......Enabled all extensions, php artisan tinker can even get connected to database with ease using app setting only.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using the following command:-

sudo apt install php7.4-pgsql   (replace 7.4 with your php version)

To check PHP version use: php -v

For more info visit: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php

[Please check php info and serach "PDO Driver for PostgreSQL" or "pdo_pgsql" after run the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWal2.png)

keywords :- for pgadmin, pgsql, postgresql, PDO Driver for PostgreSQL, pdo_pgsql @vasimraja

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `default` key in `app/config/database.php`

For postgres, default should be `'default' => 'postgres',`